# Random background when you refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

I have 14 images and I want the page to randomly select one of these when the page is loaded/refreshed.

Before I decided I wanted to use these images, I had a background with the following CSS code and it worked perfectly, and I want to use it for these new images as well:

```
 #bg {position:fixed; top: 0px; width:100%; height:100%; background: url('http://i.imgur.com/B8ubW70.jpg') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover; }

<div id="bg"></div>
```

Comment: you'll need to give us a clue on what stuff you've tried already (javascript)

Comment: i havent tried anything because i had no idea where to start lmao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Math.random() to get the random picture index.

In your case, if you are having 14 pics, use this:

```
var picno = (Math.random() * 100) % 14
```

This will return you a number between 0 and 13. After that, you can use `element.style.backgroundImage()` to change it on the onload event

window.onload = init

```
function init() {
    element.style.backgroundImage = url(pic_path_array[picno]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution use JavaScript.

The first you created bgimg folder with images:

```
> index.html 
> bgimg (folder)
> -- 1.jpg
> -- 2.jpg
> -- 3.jpg
> -- ......
```

And use JavaScript below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var totalCount = 8;
function ChangeIt()
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.background = 'bgimg/'+num+'.jpg';
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "repeat";// Background repeat
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
// Page Design
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
ChangeIt();
</script>
</html>
```